# (slice(None, None, None), None) in matplotlib plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, plot

I want to draw a plot in which the x-axis consists of intervals, like "0-5", "5-10" etc. I have 11 intervals, so I use plt.xticks(np.array(0, 11), 11Intervals) to map the x labels. However in next step plt.plot(correX, 11Intervals), there is an error warning me `(slice(None, None, None), None)`.
I search on the web to get help, and the most answer suggests using iloc/loc to fix it. But my variables type in there is Numpy, even changing it to DataFrame doesn't help at all. How to solve this problem?
Below are my codes and data:

```
def DateCalculate():
    Xindex = ["0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30", "30-50", "50-70", "70-100", "100-150", "150-200"]
    correX = np.array(range(0, 11))
    plt.xticks(correX ,Xindex)
    plt.plot(correX, res)
    plt.show()
```

data in variable res:

```
                 0
(-0.001, 5.0]   58
(5.0, 10.0]     46
(10.0, 15.0]    12
(15.0, 20.0]     9
(20.0, 25.0]     7
(25.0, 30.0]     5
(30.0, 50.0]    15
(50.0, 70.0]     7
(70.0, 100.0]   13
(100.0, 150.0]  12
(150.0, 200.0]  13
[11 rows x 1 columns]
type is DataFrame
```

Here are the trace codes:

```
exception has occurred: KeyError       (note: full exception trace is shown but execution is paused at: _run_module_as_main)
(slice(None, None, None), None)

  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\range.py", line 388, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key)
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3458, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 1327, in _check_1d
    ndim = x[:, None].ndim
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 488, in _plot_args
    y = _check_1d(xy[1])
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 312, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1632, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "D:\pycharm\python3.10\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2757, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "D:\pycharm\simulate\python_simulate\PolyHack\DataFasterRead.py", line 34, in DateCalculate
    plt.plot(correX, res)
  File "D:\pycharm\simulate\python_simulate\PolyHack\DataFasterRead.py", line 37, in <module>
    DateCalculate()
```

And this is where codes stopped:

```
@doc(Int64Index.get_loc)
def get_loc(self, key, method=None, tolerance=None):
    if method is None and tolerance is None:
        if is_integer(key) or (is_float(key) and key.is_integer()):
            new_key = int(key)
            try:
                return self._range.index(new_key)
            except ValueError as err:
                raise KeyError(key) from err
        raise KeyError(key) # <-- (bug occurred in here)
    return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
```

Comment: I don't get the `data in res`, is it have different parentheses?

Comment: Can you give the full traceback of your exception, formatted as code? The message you're giving is very unclear, and so it is going to be very hard to resolve for us, since we don't have your data to actually try plotting for ourselves.

Comment: @Blckknght, Hi thank you for your reply, now I have updated my question. Hope this could help you. But I have already shown all the data needed to draw the plot.  And for Rizquuula, that word is not code, just an explanation.